# xquery performance & patterns resources

Tags: xquery

Can anyone suggest me some good reading about Xquery performance and design patterns.
I am not looking for something specific to webapp or DB, just about Xquery and Engines.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look to http://patterns.28msec.com

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to user457056's pointer, you could read something about the [XQuery Execution Model](http://www.xquery.co.nz/about_xquery/xquery_execution). If you are looking for performance numbers, I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.marklogic.com/inside-marklogic is very MarkLogic specific, but has lots of good details on what makes MarkLogic fast.

Comment: See also the code review advice at http://blakeley.com/wordpress/archives/518